# Cygwin cmake problems on windows

Tags: c++, c, cmake, gtk, cygwin

I am trying to cmake on windows computer. I encountered following error in CMakeError.log

```
Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/ninja.exe cmTC_ff288 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_ff288.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_ff288.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o 
/usr/bin/cc   -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wextra -Wall -Wno-expansion-to-defined -Wno-psabi -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wwrite-strings -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -Wcast-align -Wno-tautological-compare  -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-exceptions -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_ff288.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o -c CheckSymbolExists.c
CheckSymbolExists.c:2:10: fatal error: pthread_np.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <pthread_np.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.


File /cygdrive/f/gtkwebkit/webkitgtk-2.34.1/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
/* */
#include <pthread_np.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
#ifndef pthread_main_np
  return ((int*)(&pthread_main_np))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? Since it is a temp file I could not modify this line of include

Comment: "I encountered following error in **CMakeError.log**" - That file contains results of compilation of many snippets which are intended determine features of your system. Content of that file is **never a problem** by itself. If configuration fails, then **output** of CMake should contain the error message. Look for that message **above** the line suggested to look into `CMakeError.log`.

Comment: You are trying to build something., What is it? What exact command are you using?

Comment: I am trying to build gtkwebkit with command: cmake -DPORT=GTK -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -GNinja -DENABLE_MINIBROWSER=ON

Comment: `pthread_np.h` does not belong to any Cygwin packages. It seems a BSD specific header